# React - set state doesn't change in callback function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not able to read current state inside `refreshWarehouseCallback` function. Why?
My component:

```
export function Schedules({ tsmService, push, pubsub }: Props) {
    const [myState, setMyState] = useState<any>(initialState);

 useEffect(() => {
        service
            .getWarehouses()
            .then((warehouses) =>
                getCurrentWarehouseData(warehouses) // inside of this function I can without problems set myState
            )
            .catch(() => catchError());

        const pushToken = push.subscribe('public/ttt/#');
        const pubSubToken = pubsub.subscribe(
            'push:ttt.*',
            refreshWarehouseCallback // HERE IS PROBLEM, when I try to read current state from this function I get old data, state changed in other functions cannot be read in thi function
        );

        return () => {
            pubsub.unsubscribe(pubSubToken);
            push.unsubscribe(pushToken);
        };
    }, []);

...

function refreshWarehouseCallback(eventName: string, content: any) {
      const {warehouseId} = myState; // undefined!!!
      case pushEvents.ramp.updated: {
}
}


return (
        <Views
            warehouses={myState.warehouses}
            allRamps={myState.allRamps}
            currentWarehouse={myState.currentWarehouse}
            pending={myState.pending}
            error={myState.error}
        />
```

I have to use `useRef` to store current state additionally to be able to rerender the whole component.

My question is - is there any other solution without `useRef`? Where is the problem? Calback function doesn't work with `useState` hook?

Answer (score 1):

Your pub/sub pattern does not inherit React's states. Whenever `subscribe` is triggered, and your callback function is initialized, that callback will not get any new values from `myState`.

To be able to use React's states, you can wrap `refreshWarehouseCallback` into another function like below

```js
//`my state` is passed into the first function (the function wrapper)
//the inner function is your original function
const refreshWarehouseCallback =
  (myState) => (eventName: string, content: any) => {
    const { warehouseId } = myState;
    //your other logic
  };
```

And then you can add another `useEffect` to update `subscribe` after state changes (in this case, `myState` updates)

```js
 //a new state to store the updated pub/sub after every clean-up
const [pubSubToken, setPubSubToken] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  //clean up when your state updates
  if (pubSubToken) {
    pubsub.unsubscribe(pubSubToken);
  }
  const updatedPubSubToken = pubsub.subscribe(
    "push:ttt.*",
    refreshWarehouseCallback(myState) //execute the function wrapper to pass `myState` down to your original callback function
  );

  //update new pub/sub token
  setPubSubToken(updatedPubSubToken);

  return () => {
    pubsub.unsubscribe(updatedPubSubToken);
  };

//add `myState` as a dependency
}, [myState]);

//you can combine this with your previous useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  const pushToken = push.subscribe("public/ttt/#");

  return () => {
    pubsub.unsubscribe(pushToken);
  };
}, []);
```